# Group a list of providers by their type using pug

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

I'm trying to group a list of users based on their specialties. For example: I want to group all Family Medicine providers and display their names:

Family Medicine:
 - List item
 - List item
 - List item

This is my js controller:

```
exports.provider_list = function(req, res, next) {

  provider.find()
    .sort([['SpecialtyName', 'ascending']])
    .exec(function (err, list_providers) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      //Successful, so render
      res.render('provider_list', { title: 'Provider List', list_providers:  list_providers});
    });

};
```

Pug list:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title

  ul.list-group
  each val in list_providers

    li 
      a(href=val.url) #{val.SpecialtyName}
      |   #{val.ProviderName}

  else
    li There are no provider.
```

Comment: where is `if` in your pug ?

Comment: I think the else is part of the each. I don't have an if statement for this.

Comment: OK, sorry you are right. Well, is there any sample of  html or drawing to understand what are you trying to achive ?

Comment: I would like a list categorized: With a heading and below that all the items belonging to that category.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand , you want to list all provider names grouped by specialty names.

And I guess your data (`list_providers`) looks like that :

```
[{
    "ProviderName": "P1",
    "SpeacialyName": "S1",
    "url" : "url_1"
  }, {
    "ProviderName": "P2",
    "SpeacialyName": "S2"
  }, {
    "ProviderName": "P3",
    "SpeacialyName": "S3"
  }, {
    "ProviderName": "P3",
    "SpeacialyName": "S1"
  }, {
    "ProviderName": "P4",
    "SpeacialyName": "S2"
  }]
```

If your data is like above. You can modify your data convert it to like this :

```
[{
        "SpeacialyName": "S1",
        "url": "url_1",
        "ProviderNames": ["P1", "P3"]
    }, {
        "SpeacialyName": "S2",
        "ProviderNames": ["P2", "P4"]
    }, {
        "SpeacialyName": "S3",
        "ProviderNames": ["P3"]
    }
]
```

And here is convertion code for backend :

```
//Successful, so render
      var providers = {}
      for (var i = 0; i < list_providers.length; i++) {
        var item = list_providers[i];
        if (!providers[item.SpeacialyName]) {
          providers[item.SpeacialyName] = item;
          providers[item.SpeacialyName].ProviderNames = [item.ProviderName];
        } else {
          providers[item.SpeacialyName].ProviderNames.push(item.ProviderName)
        }
        delete providers[item.SpeacialyName].ProviderName;
      }

      //convert object to array
      var providersArray = [];
      for (const item in providers) {
        providersArray.push(providers[item])
      }

      res.render('provider_list', { title: 'Provider List', list_providers: providersArray });
```

Finally, here is pug file to list

```
ul.list-group
    each val in list_providers
        li 
            a(href=val.url) #{val.SpeacialyName}
            ul
                each name in val.ProviderNames
                    li
                        a(href="")=name
                else
                    li There are no speacialy.

    else
        li There are no provider.
```